# django - html code in a dict gets escaped

Tags: django

Howdeh!

I have this dict:

```
PERIOD = [
    (1,"&lt; 3 mnths"),
    (2,"3 - 6mths"),
    (3,"6mths - 1yr"),
    (4,"1 - 2yrs"),
    (5,"&gt; 2yrs"),
]
```

Which i want to dispay in my django page. Before, I used to have the point braces `<` instead of the `&lt;` stuff, but then i realised that not only was i displaying a drop down, but in other parts of the site i was displaying the contents (so, you know, the 3rd item only).

With the above, when i display say the 3rd item only? Everything looks fine. But when i display the dict as a select dropdown? Then django decides to not decode the `&gt;` things.

Given i send the dict to the template with this:

```
periodChoice = ChoiceField(label='', choices=PERIOD, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'regDropDown'}))
```

and in the template i display it like this:

```
Choose from  {{ theForm.periodChoice }}
```

how do i get the template do what i want it to do? I tried asking nicely, i even tried a |safe... no luck!

Comment: can you try {{theForm.get_theForm.periodChoice_display|safe}}

Comment: that didn't do anything... nothing was displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

PERIOD = [
    (1, mark_safe("&lt; 3 mnths")),
    (2,"3 - 6mths"),
    (3,"6mths - 1yr"),
    (4,"1 - 2yrs"),
    (5, mark_safe("&gt; 2yrs")),
]
```

and leave the rest as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify `|safe` as a filter in the template.

```
{{ theForm.periodChoice|safe }}
```